# Java: Error in code for a Recursive Maze for using Java

Tags: java, recursion, maze

this code below is for a maze via recursion and is supposed to solve the maze. There are three different txt files that it reads from S is the start, G is the goal, X is a barrier and O is a free space

```
GOOOOXO //maze1
XXOXOOX
OXOOOXX
XXXOOXO
XXXXOXX
SOOOOOX
XXXXXXX
```

---

```
XOOOOXO //maze2
XXOXOOG
OXOOOXX
XXXOOOX
XXXXOXX
SOOOOOX
XXXXXXX
```

---

```
XOOOOXO //maze3
XXOXOXG
OXOOOXX
XXXOOOX
XXXXOXX
SOOOOOX
XXXXXXX
```

---

These are the mazes. maze1 and maze2 have a solution but every time I run it, it returns "unsolvable". I'm not sure where the error is. Here is the full code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Maze2
{
 private static char[][] maze;
 private static int startrow, startcol, finishrow, finishcol;
 private static ArrayList<String> mazeBuffer;
 public static void initializeMaze(String fileName)
 {
  startrow = startcol = finishrow = finishcol = -1;
  mazeBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
  int numcols = 0;
  try
  {
   Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
   while(file.hasNext())
   {    
    String nextLine = file.nextLine();
    mazeBuffer.add(nextLine);
    if (nextLine.length() > numcols)
     numcols = nextLine.length();
   }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println(fileName + " has an issue");
  }
  int numrows = mazeBuffer.size();
  maze = new char[numrows][numcols];
  for (int r = 0; r < numrows; r ++)
  {
   String row = mazeBuffer.get(r);
   for (int c = 0; c < numcols; c++)
   {
    if(row.length() >= c)
     maze[r][c]=row.charAt(c);
    else
     maze[r][c]='*';
    if (maze[r][c] == 'S')
    {
     startrow = r;
     startcol = c;
    }
    if (maze[r][c] == 'G')
    {
     finishrow = r;
     finishcol = c;
    }
   }
  }
  System.out.println("Maze loaded");
 }
 public static void printMaze()
 {
  for (char[] row: maze)
  {
   for (char c: row)
    System.out.print(c);
   System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println();
 }
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  initializeMaze("maze3.txt");
  printMaze();
  if (solveMaze(startrow, startcol))
   printMaze();
  else
   System.out.println("Unsolvable.");
 } 
public static boolean solveMaze(int r, int c)
{
  if(r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= maze.length || c >= maze[0].length)
    return false;  
  if(maze[r][c]=='G')
    return true;
  if (maze[r][c] != '0'|| maze[r][c] != 'S')
    return false; 
 maze[r][c]='A';
 if(solveMaze(r-1,c))
 {
   maze[r][c]= '#';
   return true;
 }
  if(solveMaze(r+1,c))
 {
   maze[r][c]='#';
   return true;
 }
   if(solveMaze(r,c-1))
 {
   maze[r][c]='#';
   return true;
 }
   if(solveMaze(r,c+1))
 {
   maze[r][c]='#';
   return true;
 }
  else{
  return false;
    }
   }
}
```

---

If all is correct, mazes 1 and 2 should be solvable but as of now they are not for some reason. plz help it's a project due soon and I can't figure it out.

Comment: If your code is not behaving as expected then you should first fire up the debugger of your favorite IDE to find out why this is occurring

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have tried, but it all compiles fine and runs with no issue. The first two mazes should return a solution, but for some reason return unsolvable

Comment: I'm not talking about compilation problems but logic problems, and again the solution is to debug. If you've done this then share the fruits of your debugging efforts with us in your question. The question currently shows no evidence of your having done this and risks being closed for being too broad

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have been looking at this for hours but I can't find out why it's returning unsolvable for the first two mazes. With the conditions I set, the maze should be able to solve. Obviously there is an error somewhere...(i would guess the if statements) but I can't find it

Comment: @tbot I think you have misunderstood HovercraftFullOfEels's suggestion. There's no need to look at your code for hours. A debugger is a tool that will allow you to step through your code as it executes so you can see what it is actually doing, not what you think it should be doing. Your IDE will have one and learning how to use it will be a very valuable skill to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the condition if you are on a valid path.
The first error is, that you are checking for the number 0 instead of the capital letter O. 
The second error is the combination of the two conditions. If you start at 'S' you are obviously not at an 'O'. So your condition tells you, that you are not on a valid path. The check should be:
        if(!(maze[r][c] == 'O'|| maze[r][c] == 'S'))

If you fix this, everything should be working fine.